# Delphi - Function do RAP Code Report Builder

Tags: delphi, relatório

Olá.

Estou com um problema para executar as function de um template de um Report Builder no Delphi.
Identifiquei que o erro ocorre quando dentro da function tem outros métodos, tipo FormatFloat, StrToFloat ...
Por algum motivo durante o evento do PRINT não está conseguindo executar esses métodos.

```
ppReport.AllowPrintToFile     := True;
ppReport.DeviceType           := 'PDF';
ppReport.TextFileName         := sNomeArquivo;
ppReport.ShowPrintDialog      := False;
ppReport.ShowCancelDialog     := false;
ppReport.ShowAutoSearchDialog := false;
ppReport.ModalCancelDialog    := false;
ppReport.Print;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiquei que o erro estava ocorrendo porque os Pipe estava sendo criando em outros formulário e não no que eu estava passando no parametro.
Com isso quando a function tentava acessar qualquer Pipe dava erro.